# Bundle.IncludeDirectory in MVC5 outputting wrong paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded an MVC 4 project to MVC 5 as part of the upgrade to VS2013 and I'm getting a strange behaviour with Bundles and Minification. I then tried in a new MVC 5 project and also have the same issue. This is what I'm doing:

Start with a new MVC 5 project and add the following files

```
app\0.js
app\a
app\a\b
app\a\c
app\a\b\1.js
app\a\c\6.js
app\a\c\d
app\a\c\e
app\a\c\d\2.js
app\a\c\d\3.js
app\a\c\d\4.js
app\a\c\e\5.js
```

Then in my BundleConfig I add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true));
```

And in my view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

Now when I browse to the page with Bundling and Minification Off, this is what's rendered:

```
<script src="/app/0.js"></script>
<script src="/app/1.js"></script>
<script src="/app/6.js"></script>
<script src="/app/2.js"></script>
<script src="/app/3.js"></script>
<script src="/app/4.js"></script>
<script src="/app/5.js"></script>
```

Note that all files are at `/app` and the subdirectories got lost in the process.

I've been using this for a long time in an MVC 4 project without any problems.

Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package is 1.1.1.

Does anyone experienced this?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I should have searched better. It's a known issue.

http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105

Comment: Wow... between the "sanitizer" (Feb 2012) that stripped out all useful html and now this... I'm wondering how they keep releasing packages that break functionality.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I always praised the stability and compatibility of the .NET releases (as opposed to, say, Java :)). But since Microsoft started to do releases release ASP.NET stuff in form of NuGet packages it became a dependency mess.

Comment: Same problem here. One thing to note - it works fine in Release mode when everything is bundled together, just not in Debug with individual files.

Comment: Thanks for locating this info. It looks like we'll be sticking with MVC4 until some of these issues are corrected.

Comment: The issue has been fixed already. Not sure why the ticket is still active though.